# Need to replace part of a textbox string using iMacros

Tags: string, replace, textbox, imacros

I have domain directories that need to be updated. The directories look something like this:
'subdomain.mydomain.com/Directory/Sub_Directory

I need to replace: subdomain.mydomain.com/

with: newsub.newdomain.com/

Is there a way to do this with iMacros for Firefox. I have the looping structure working to get in and access each of the 300 text fields but couldn't see if there was a way to change this string.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SET newDir EVAL("'subdomain.mydomain.com/Directory/Sub_Directory'.replace('subdomain.mydomain.com', 'newsub.newdomain.com')")
'PROMPT {{newDir}}
```

Comment: Thank you Shugar for the quick response. This has gotten me going in the right direction, but I am still having an issue getting the text out of the textbox to replace the subdomain,mydomain.com/ part. So I need to do what you provided on a string that is being pulled from a textbox form. Any additional information is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: No one can help you not seeing the html-code where textboxes are. On the other hand, read the wiki about data extraction and try to record the macro in 'iMacros' yourselves.

Comment: I was able to accomplish what I needed by Using EXTRACT in the iMacro combined with what you helped me with before. Here is the final macro:       TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:SearchURL EXTRACT=TXT, SET newURL EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".replace('subdomain.mydomain.com/', 'newsubdomain.newdomain.com')")